# Manual Memory Management VS ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm reading a book on Objective C, and I was wondering about 2 things:

1.Should I take the time currently to read a whole chapter on memory management since we mostly use ARC?(only asking this question to make sure im managing time properly)

2.If you are doing a really good job on manual management, can you get to better performance than using ARC? (like that your app will work faster)

tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should at least familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of the manual memory management, because ARC uses it under the hood. You need to learn at least about three things: `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease`. This will help you understand discussions about ARC's inner working.
2. ARC is mostly a compiler trick (with some support from the runtime). You can write less code, but you cannot get better performance from it. Essentially, ARC lets you deal with memory management *declaratively*, while the manual management uses *imperative* style. However, both systems call the same methods from the runtime.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer. Regarding the second point, I was trying to understand if you can get better performance with manual memory management(if it's done right)? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @JohnBigs the beauty of ARC is that it does not make you give up any control: if you want to release an object early, you can `nil` out its pointer to force deletion; if you need to drain an autorelease pool, you can use the new `@autorelease` construct, and so on.

Comment: ARC actually can get you both better and worse performance in various situations. The better performance is due to a very clever trick it plays where it can remove autoreleases in situations that humans cannot (see 'callerAcceptsFastAutorelease' here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-arr.mm). The slowness is because when ARC cannot be absolutely certain, it errs on the side of extra retains and releases for safety. In *most* cases though, ARC should be performance-neutral.

Comment: A couple more things on the performance angle. First, as mentioned in one of the WWDC sessions that introduced ARC, `@autoreleasepool` (which is available in both MRC and ARC) is faster than NSAutoreleasePool. Second, some of ARC's behaviors can reduce object lifetimes, which can lower your app's memory high-water mark, which can reduce the change of causing page-outs. Page-outs are a system-wide speed bump, so avoiding them is, in some sense, a speed gain. (Also, on iOS, using too much memory will get your process killed, so avoiding that is an even bigger gain there.)

Answer (score 1):

1、Of course you should.ARC is based on the same memory management,just let the compiler do the same work.If you want to master a kind of technology，try to know how does it work is a faster way.

2、Actually,they do the same performance.Just let the compiler do what did you do before.For when you retain an object(which is a property) in the class, we always release in the dealloc.you alloc an object in a method,assign to local pointer,it will be release when the stack memory of this method clean up;if you retain it in the method to the method's local variable you release it in the same place.Then you will be find they are all predictable.why not let the machine do it?